# MLE estimate of normal distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, maximum-likelihood, unbiased-estimator, exponential-family

I am quoting this from Greene's econometrics book:

> The occasional statement that the properties of the MLE are only optimal in large samples is not true, however. It can be shown that when sampling is from an exponential family of distributions, there will exist sufficient statistics. If so, MLEs will be functions of them, which means that when minimum variance unbiased estimators exist, they will be MLEs. [See Stuart and Ord (1989).] Most applications in econometrics do not involve exponential families, so the appeal of the MLE remains primarily its asymptotic properties.

So why is the variance estimate biased downward in MLE for a normal distribution? That is, given that it is an exponential family distribution, its MLE estimate should be unbiased and minimum variance.

Comment: You seem to invert the logic of the statement: "... **when** MVUEs exist, they will be MLEs." To apply this correctly, you must have in mind the MVUE of a Normal variance.  What is it?

Comment: @whuber Isn't bias corrected version of variance estimator of normal variance MVUE?